# Has anyone successfully implemented GDX Pay for iOS?

Tags: ios, libgdx, in-app-purchase, robovm

I've been running my head around the implementation for quite some time. I have been unable to do so.
I've done all the pre-requisites, setting up the test users in sandbox, setting up the IAP product on itunesconnect etc. While on device, I sign out of the app store from Settings.

I have updated to the latest available GDX and GDXPay versions,

```
gdxVersion = '1.9.1'
roboVMVersion = '1.12.0'
gdxpayVersion = '0.9.2'
```

However, the application crashes at the time of calling `installIAP()` without giving me a sign in prompt. The sign in prompt however does appear after the application crashes.

```
 IOSLauncher[3511:1011291] [info] IAP: IAP: gdx-pay successfully instantiated. [GdxPay/AppleIOS] Installing purchase observer...

[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Requesting products...

 IOSLauncher[3511:1011291] [debug] IOSApplication: resumed

[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Products successfully received!

[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Purchase observer successfully installed!

[GdxPay/AppleIOS] There are 0 unfinished transactions. Try to finish...

WARN: Failed to call getClassDomain() for the NSError subclass org.robovm.apple.foundation.NSCocoaError

WARN: Failed to call getClassDomain() for the NSError subclass org.robovm.apple.storekit.SKError

[GdxPay/AppleIOS] Transaction failed: Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=0 "You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time.}
 com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Transaction failed: Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=0 "You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time.} at com.vxxxxxxs.pxxxxxxxg.app.PxxxxLxxxg$1.handlePurchaseError(PxxxxxLxxxxg.java:70) at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleTransactionObserver.updatedTransactions(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java:392) at com.badlogic.gdx.pay.ios.apple.PurchaseManageriOSApple$AppleTransactionObserver.$cb$paymentQueue$updatedTransactions$(PurchaseManageriOSApple.java) at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(Native Method) at org.robovm.apple.uikit.UIApplication.main(UIApplication.java:395) at com.vxxxxxs.pxxxxxxxxg.app.IOSLauncher.main(IOSLauncher.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Transaction failed: Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=0 "You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=You are not authorized to make purchases of this InApp in Sandbox at this time.} ... 5 more
```